# Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit Error in Logstash

Tags: logstash

Click on below link to see my logstash code

[image]

Following is the error

> ERROR] 2019-10-04 16:17:13.918 [Converge PipelineAction::Create]
>   jdbc - Unknown setting 'jbdc_password' for jdbc [ERROR] 2019-10-04
>   16:17:13.924 [Converge PipelineAction::Create] agent - Failed to
>   execute
>   action{:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
>   :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable
>   to configure plugins: (ConfigurationError) Something is wrong with
>   your configuration.",
>   :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.(CompiledPipeline.java:100)",
>   "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:60)",
>   "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.call(JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen)",
>   "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:837)",
>   "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1156)",
>   "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuperSplatArgs(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1143)",
>   "org.jruby.ir.targets.InstanceSuperInvokeSite.invoke(InstanceSuperInvokeSite.java:39)",
>   "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:26)",
>   "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:91)",
>   "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:90)",
>   "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)",
>   "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)",
>   "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:915)",
>   "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)",
>   "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:183)",
>   "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36)",
>   "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$**VARARGS**(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)",
>   "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:91)",
>   "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:90)",
>   "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:183)",
>   "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:326)",
>   "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:136)",
>   "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:77)",
>   "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:129)",
>   "org.jruby.RubyProc`enter code here`.call(RubyProc.java:295)",
>   "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:274)",
>   "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:270)",
>   "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)",
>   "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)"]} warning: thread
>   "Converge PipelineAction::Create" terminated with exception
>   (report_on_exception is true): LogStash::Error: Don't know how to
>   handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for
>   `PipelineAction::Create<main>` create at
>   org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109add at
>   org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37 converge_state at
>   /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339 [ERROR]
>   2019-10-04 16:17:13.930 [Agent thread] agent - An exception happened
>   when converging configuration {:exception=>LogStash::Error,
>   :message=>"Don't know how to handle
>   `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for
>   `PipelineAction::Create<main>`",
>   :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in
>   `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in`
>   add'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in `block
>   in converge_state'"]} [FATAL] 2019-10-04 16:17:13.949
>   [LogStash::Runner] runner - An unexpected error occurred!
>   {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle`
>   Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException`for`
>   PipelineAction::Create`>,
>   :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:109:in`
>   create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:37:in
>   `add'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:339:in`block
>   in converge_state'"]} [ERROR] 2019-10-04 16:17:13.988
>   [LogStash::Runner] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is unclear what you want help with. Please add your code to the post and an explanation about how to run the code to reproduce the issue you are having.

Answer (score 3):

> Unknown setting 'jbdc_password' for jdbc

That should be jdbc_password, not jbdc_password.